# Is it possible to embed form inputs into a rich text editor document model?

Tags: forms, pdf, ckeditor, rich-text-editor, quill

I am building a project with Django 2.2.4 and PostgreSQL 11.4. I am using JSON database fields to store data in JSON arrays.

In my app users create documents using "rich text editor" that provides standard text/image features already.

---

I also want to enable users create the document to drag and drop form inputs into the body of the document so that once the document is "published" other users can view the document an add input values to these fields before submitting and saving the document again.

Now, I'm trying to figure out conceptually the most efficient way to approach this.

I thought the first step would be to use an abstracted rich text editor which separates the document structure from the HTML, e.g. CKEditor or Quill; if I was to serialise the document with form inputs included I could in theory store templates in one JSONField and inputs in another.

[This](https://gist.github.com/manigandham/65543a0bc2bf7006a487) list is a really useful overview of various editors, but despite having read a lot of documentation it's not clear if this approach would be either correct or actually possible.

Does anyone have any similar experiences?

Comment: have you tried embedding a Google Form?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this isn't possible unfortunately.

Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do with this?